# Почему не создаётся картинка - node js

Tags: node.js, png, fs

Делаю программу которая берёт картинку пользователя, её координаты и потом берёт картинку с pixelplanet.fun по этим координатам, потом при помощи цикла сравнивается на совпадения попиксельно, но почему то картинка не создаётся

```js
module.exports = async function (img, x, y, msg){
    
    msg.channel.send('One second...')
    
    const { bitmap: { width, height } } =  await Jimp.read(img);

    const x2 = parseInt(x) + width; 
    const y2 = parseInt(y) + height;

    const x1 = parseInt(x);
    const y1 = parseInt(y);

    const ID_PPimg = await loadImageFromPP(x1, y1, x2, y2);// получаем картинку с pixelplanet.fun
    
    const res = await fetch(img);
    const imgID = Date.now();
    
    fs.writeFileSync(`./images/${imgID}_tmp.png`, Buffer.from(await res.arrayBuffer()));

    const img1 = PNG.sync.read(fs.readFileSync(`./images/${imgID}_tmp.png`));
    const img2 = PNG.sync.read(fs.readFileSync(`./images/${ID_PPimg}_scr.png`)); 
    
    let rgba1 = img1.data, rgba2 = img2.data;

    const diff = new PNG({ width, height });

    let i=0;
    for(y=0; y<height; y++) {
        for(x=0; x<width; x++, i+=4){
            if(rgba1[i+3]<255){
                diff.data[i  ] = 0;
                diff.data[i+1] = 0;
                diff.data[i+2] = 0;
                diff.data[i+3] = 0;
            } else if(rgba1[i] == rgba2[i] && rgba1[i+1] == rgba2[i+1] && rgba1[i+1] == rgba2[i+1]){
                let average = (rgba1[i] + rgba1[i+2] + rgba1[i+2])/3;
                diff.data[i  ] = average;
                diff.data[i+1] = average; 
                diff.data[i+2] = average;
                diff.data[i+3] = 255;
            } else{
                diff.data[i  ] = 255;
                diff.data[i+1] = 0;
                diff.data[i+2] = 0;
                diff.data[i+3] = 255;
            };
            
        };
    };

    


    fs.createWriteStream(`./images/${imgID}_test.png`, PNG.sync.write(diff));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо `` fs.createWriteStream(`./images/${imgID}_test.png`, PNG.sync.write(diff)); ``
Изменить на `` fs.writeFileSync(`./images/${ID_PPimg}_test.png`, PNG.sync.write(diff)); ``